# Can I bring a 30000 mAh power bank on board the aircraft?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, batteries

Well I am 24 and this is my first time travelling overseas. Kind of embarrassed, but I finally have enough money for travelling.

I would like to ask can I take [this](https://www.aukey.com/products/30000mah-power-bank-with-quick-charge-3-0) 30000mAh Power Bank, onboard the plane? Most of the time I will not be at the hotel, hence why I need a larger powerbank.

Comment: Overseas = from where to where? There's no need to be embarrassed, everyone is a first time traveler at some point.

Comment: From malaysia to taiwan

Comment: I have a powerbank whose labels are wearing off but I think it’s 10000 mAh after searching the Yodobashi page. It lasts me for an entire day of Pokémon GO so unless you’re a player with more than one phone or have other extremely battery consuming apps you should be fine with much less ;) Incidentally, I’m going to Taiwan soon, too.

Comment: Look for a 26800 mah power bank instead, there are plenty on Amazon, and they are designed for airplane carry with a capacity below 100Wh written on the enclosure.

Comment: Eh, I'm older than you, and I've only done road trips still.

Comment: Maybe add the name of the airline, they may have their own specific rules outside the usual guidelines

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Their [website](https://www.aukey.com/products/30000mah-power-bank-with-quick-charge-3-0), which you link to, has this FAQ

> **Can you take portable chargers on planes?**
>
> Most airlines allow lithium batteries that do not exceed 100W/hours in the carry-on luggage. You can find the product specific information on the outside of the power bank. Also, consult your airlines for specific information about your flight and travel locations as there may be different regulations between airlines.

According to publicly available images of the product, and by the correct calculations in the other answers, **Capacity of this power bank is 111Wh**.

This product might not be allowed on an airplane without the approval of the airline. Obviously the exact answer will depend upon what do they decide at that time, and it's hard to give a definitive answer.

Please see [IATA guideliness](https://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/dgr/Documents/passenger-lithium-battery.pdf) kindly shared by [@jcaron](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/147502/first-time-travel/147508?noredirect=1#comment364977_147508).

<sub>* Before someone comes along saying carry-on prohibition doesn't mean they can't have them in checked baggage; please note that loose lithium batteries are generally never allowed in checked baggage regardless of their capacity</sub>.

---

**Bonus Tip since you're a new traveler.**

Be nice to the staff you will interact with in due course, and no one will probably care about that battery pack and will let you board with it :) (It's not too far above the limit)

And whether you have the battery pack or not, whether you have a lot of money or not, just enjoy your trips. You aren't answerable to anybody as to what took you so long to travel for the first time.

Comment: As battery makers often play with the numbers, the capacity in mAh is more probably linked to the “native” output of the battery (starting at over 4V when fully charged at going down to barely above 3V when empty, with a “nominal” voltage at .7V) rather than the regulated output of the battery pack, so this is more likely to be 111 Wh, but this doesn’t change the end result.

Comment: The IATA guidelines for passengers are available here: https://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/dgr/Documents/passenger-lithium-battery.pdf

Comment: The electric charge (in mAh) of a power bank is not given relative to the output voltage (which may vary) but to the nominal voltage of the li-ion cells inside which are usually 3.6V or 3.7V 18650 cells.

Comment: In practice, is the airline going to check each and every power bank for the allowed energy capacity (assuming it’s not printed in huge numbers on the case)? As long as it looks like your everyday, average-sized power bank I’d be surprised if they spend any time investigating it.

Comment: @Michael I wouldn't qualify a 30Ah battery to be an everyday/average-size power bank: it's bulky, it's heavy (~600g/20oz) and may certainly bring attention of some operators. I personally carry a 26,8Ah all the time and its capacity (99,16Wh, written on its back) have been checked at security more than once (last time at CDG).

Comment: Rather annoying that they say there’s a 100w limit but then don’t tell you the official wattage of the powerbank on the site.

Comment: @Michael the airline only gets to inspect luggage in airports where security is at the gate. With centralized security they won't know who's carrying what.

Comment: The most important part is, **carry-on luggage**.  If there's a problem in the passenger cabin, they are equipped to deal with it, but in the luggage hold...no good

Comment: Note that the 100Wh limit goes for the total across any powerbanks that you take with you. 100Wh is a **lot** of power. You're likely fine with a slightly smaller powerbank. I can charge my phone for several days on my 80Wh powerbank.

Comment: How much checking depends on where he's going.  I had two power banks with me at PEK airport, both were checked despite the markings being quite small.

Answer (score 17):

From the [IATA guidelines](https://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/dgr/Documents/passenger-lithium-battery.pdf), **all lithium batteries are subject to regulation**, with specific rules depending on the type of device (portable electronic-device, medical device or spare battery).

**A power banks is considered a spare battery** (not a portable electronic device) and are restricted to carry-on luggage only (i.e. prohibited in checked luggage) and further restricted based on its capacity rating :

- Below 100Wh, the battery is allowed in carry on (with a maximum of 20
  per passenger) without any operator approval needed.
- Between 100Wh and 160Wh, only two battery are allowed and the
  operator approval is needed.
- Above 160Wh is prohibited in passenger flights.

To avoid any issue, you should target a power bank with a **capacity rating below the 100Wh threshold**, even if that implies to take two of them.

If the energy capacity (in watt-hour) of the power bank is not specified in the product sheet, it can be deduced from the charge capacity (in ampere-hour or milliampere-hour) and the nominal voltage with the following formula : 1 Wh = 1V x 1Ah. But note that the electric charge of a power bank is not given relative to the output voltage (which may vary) but to the nominal voltage of the li-ion battery pack inside which is usually a bunch of 3.6V or 3.7V 18650 cells in series.

Your 30 000 mAh power bank would have a capacity around 110Wh (30 Ah x 3,6-3,7 V) depending on the cell type. **Power banks designed for airplane carry are around 27 000 mAh** to fit the 100Wh restriction and the capacity (usually 99,xWh) should be specified in the product sheet and written on the enclosure to avoid any issue.

Answer (score 5):

The "Aukey" power bank PB-Y3 does not appear to have a Wh rating marked on the outside of the case, based on studying a [Russian](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3ZV6BA6bvA) review video.

The typical airline 100Wh limit could be considered to be exceeded then, by the airport security personnel since 3.7V * 30,000 = 111Wh. I have seen them take power banks away from people (in Asia- US security seems to be more lax in that regard).

For what it's worth (from a teardown video) the internals contain 3 pyramidal cells marked 3.7V 10000mAh so the rating is as honest as the Chinese battery maker (BTC, apparently). I suspect it's somewhat- "optimistic" in this case, but that's just my opinion (based on seeing a lot of other dubious claims- and a case of BTC batteries I was gifted because they didn't meet specifications).

Personally I would get a [Huawei](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/accessories/20000-qc-powerbank/) or Xiaomi 20,000mAh power bank rather than this one, if it was available off the shelf. They're brand-name cell phone makers (so they definitely know batteries) and have good reputations for quality and **safety**. I have hiked as long as 13 hours using an iPhoneX running mapping applications using the phone and an alleged 11,000mAh power bank (low power mode on the phone much of the time). There was plenty of juice left in the power bank if I got a chance to charge it mostly. It takes quite some time (as much as 9 or 10 hours) to charge some of the power banks, and you probably want them close by while charging.

Keep in mind, the higher capacity power banks are significantly heavier and you have to lug all that weight around or nothing. There are often opportunities to charge your phone at restaurants, cafes, workplaces etc. and unless you're doing a lot of video work or obsessively playing with your phone you may not use that much juice. However, mapping applications do tend to use a lot of power- and, at least on my phone, they keep the screen on consuming even more power.

Safety wise, keep in mind that 111Wh is 400kJ of energy. A .45 ACP bullet carries 0.5 to 0.8kJ. A stick of dynamite is about 1000kJ.

Edit: For what it's worth, I just bought a Huawei 20,000mAh power bank myself, model CP22QC (CNY269) and it is clearly marked **on the unit** (where anyone inspecting can read it) as **68.97Wh**, well under the 100Wh limit, so they are assuming an average lithium ion battery voltage over the discharge curve of 3.4485VDC. Note that there is a common (rather optimistic) misconception that the mAh ratings quoted apply to the **output**. The output will be less by the voltage ratio and even less than that because the DC-DC conversion process is not 100% efficient. At 85% efficiency you might get 11,500mAh from the output.

Note & tl;dr: I'm certainly not endorsing any particular brand, but I would suggest buying a major world-wide cell phone brand.

Comment: That’s a good answer which goes deeper than the face value of the question!

Comment: A tub of lard is 15000kJ. You've got a logical fallacy somewhere.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky The tub of lard is not known for it's "vent with flame" propensities A LiIon battery pack, once it get's going, can dissipate the majority of its energy in a few 10's of seconds. The results are 'impressive'. At say 200 jJ over 20 seconds = 10 kJ/sec = 10 kW (10 kW!!!!) it may not have the point impact of a '45, but it could do more gross damage.  I'd rather be thrown a flaming 30 Ah LiIon battery pack than be shot with a 45, but I may not live to regret that choice.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky It's a matter of energy release over time as Russell says. Soldiers are reputed to have cooked meals with C4, but if the energy gets released all at once, it's more dramatic.

Comment: Why don't you clarify yourself in your answer, not in a comment to me. I know what energy and power are.